# Find matching pattern of first columns between two files and print the line from each file in a third file

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I have two files one containing Server Name and IP and another containing Server Name and Machine name, For example. The files are in no real order. i have tried using a variation of Sort, awk, and sed. but the first file is not maintained very well and contains bogus data that offsets how i was planning on doing it.

Im trying to basically pattern match between the two files for only servers that are contained in both lines and print the data from the lines in both files on one line in a thrid file.

File 1:

```
Server1 10.10.10.1
Server2 10.10.10.2
....
Server154 10.10.30.8
Server155 10.10.30.9
```

File 2:

```
Server1 site site1
Server2 site site2
....
Server154 site site154
Server155 site site155
```

Output:

```
Server1 10.10.10.1 site site1
Server2 10.10.10.2 site site2
...
Server154 10.10.30.8 site site154
Server155 10.10.30.9 site site155
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}($1 in a){print a[$1],$2,$3}' file1 file2
Server1 10.10.10.1 site site1
Server2 10.10.10.2 site site2
Server154 10.10.30.8 site site154
Server155 10.10.30.9 site site155
```

Comment: yeah apparently theirs a timer, i had to wait 2 minutes before it would let me, your just to quick. :D

Answer (score -1):

Can be solved by filling an array with the first file in BEGIN, and then matching the second file agains that array.

```
awk -v f1="file1.txt" 'BEGIN { while (getline < f1) { keys[$1]=$2 } ; close(f1) }
   keys[$1] { print }' file2.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the required output and this use of `getline`,`BEGIN` and `-v` is bad practice.

Comment: All this is doing is printing lines in `file2` if the first field is also found in `file1` it is not joining the output. Getline -> http://awk.info/?tip/getline

Comment: I disagree. The point of using "-v" is so that I don't have to write the full filename in the BEGIN statement, only the variable.
Example c in "Applications" in your referenced article apply to reading data first that is referenced later, exactly the point of my example. Creating the proper output format was meant to be an excercise of the OP. If that is improper on stackoverflow I appologize.